# Android - EditText loses focus in fullscreen landscape

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-fullscreen

I have an landscape activity which has been made full screen through flags. Now I have an EditText field which when clicked loses focus after few seconds and the keyboard is still shown on screen and no EditText field shown.

How can I solve this problem ?

This is my activity in Manifest

```
<activity
     android:name=".modules.session.ClassActivity"
     android:screenOrientation="landscape"
     android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

Comment: Can you post your code.

Comment: @crammeur which code snippet you want to see whole activity or anything specific ?

Comment: Start with activity and if we need other I will say to you.